# AutoHotKey Send Hotkey key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a hotkey that sets the value of a variable and presses itself.

```
Hotkey, %UserBuild1% , Build1
Build1:
    HotbarStatus := UserBuild1
    send {%UserBuild1%}
return
```

I've tried putting a `$` sign in front like you do with `$9::` for example but that dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me.

```
;Define your hotkey - Example: Control + Alt + m
UserBuild1 = ^!m

Hotkey %UserBuild1% , Build1
Return ;don't forget or Build1 will be executed on start

Build1:
    HotbarStatus := UserBuild1
    send %UserBuild1%
    MsgBox %HotbarStatus% ;just for debugging purposes...
return
```